# Are there major differences between the metas of the different servers of Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

Like the question asks, is there a major difference between the metas of the different servers of Hearthstone? Like, are the metas slower on EU, or faster on Asia?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, the meta is always shifting, so saying that the meta is fast in general on a specific server is almost always wrong. It's a constant process of countering the Flavour of the Month. To keep track of the current meta I recommend checking out the [meta-snapshots from Tempostorm](https://tempostorm.com/hearthstone/meta-snapshot/a-wild-snapshot-appears).

However, this refers mostly to the meta in EU and NA. Both regions are so connected through tournaments and streamers that the difference in the metas (if there is even one) is too small to notice.

Asia on the other hand, is another story. Asian players seem to have a preference for weird combo decks. In the past, several crazy decks have popped up there and have disappeared quickly after. I guess they did not work that well on the western servers.
**Here some examples:**

- [Aggro Priest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfCnN.jpg)
- [9/4 Priest](http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks/104164-9-4-priest-china)
- [Aggro-Control Warrior](http://www.hearthstonetopdecks.com/decks/kranichs-blizzcon-2014-aggro-control-warrior/)

There were a lot more in the past of course, but I have to admit I have forgotten a lot of them since I am not that into Hearthstone at the moment. But you see what I mean.